# How to set up celery and django with Amazon SQS

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-sqs

I'm trying to convert videos uploaded by users in a django app. Problem is, it's eating up resources and the site becomes unavailable during this time and a new instance has to be sprung up to scale it(I'm using Elastic Beanstalk). I did some research and decided to use SQS with a worker enviroment

I set up celery and added necessary configs to the settings.py file

```
BROKER_TRANSPORT = 'sqs'
BROKER_TRANSPORT_OPTIONS = {
    'region': 'us-east-1',
    'polling_interval': 3,
    'visibility_timeout': 3600,
}
BROKER_USER = AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
BROKER_PASSWORD = AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY

CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE = 'celery-convert-video'
CELERY_QUEUES = {
    CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE: {
        'exchange': CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE,
        'binding_key': CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE,
    }
}
```

I set up the POST url to /celery-convert-video/
I also do:

video = TestVideo.objects.create(uploaded_video=videoFile)

then

ConvertVideo.delay(video_id=video.id)

to send the task to SQS. It grabs he uploaded file using a url and converts it. Locally it works but the problem comes in the cloud.

I seem to be having problems with setting up the Worker Environment because it's health always ends up becoming "Severe" and everytime I check the cause It says 100% of requests return error 4xx . Logs say it's a 403.

The tasks show up fine in SQS (but are indecipherable, just random letters, I'm guessing it's encoded?) and get "in flight" so the problem I'm assuming is the worker. I have no idea how to set it up properly.

So a few questions:

1. Do I have to use the same deployment files for the worker and the main enviroment?
2. Do I have to edit the deployment files and add a /celery-convert-video/ view in my worker environment and then send it to the equivalent ConvertVideo function in the worker?
3. How do I connect the worker to the RDS database used by the main enviroment?
4. How do I get rid of the 403 errors and get the worker health back to green?

If anyone has a step by step tutorial or something that they can point me to that would be a big help!

P.S. I'm not an expert in cloud computing, It's actually my first stab at it so forgive my ignorance..